# GetElementById form a "master" inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, master-pages

Ok this is in javascript, so I have a iframe inside a contente place holder of a master page.
Something like this.

1-MasterPage

2-contentePlaceHolder

3-Iframe

When i'am in the iframe how do I get a control with "GetElementById" from the masterPage??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :
Provided that masterpage and iframe src belong to same domain , let's say you have a button in iframe , on 'onclick' event of that button write this code :

```
var P = parent.document.getElementById("element_id") ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot.  Your iFrame is unaware of the master page holding it.

Comment: If your iframe src and parent page are both on the same domain then it is possible...

Answer (score 2):

If both your parent page and iframe src are on the same domain then using [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) you can do something like this from the iframe's src page:

`$(parent.document).find('#myElement').hide('slow');`